# print stylesheet, one page prints and cuts off remaining text

Tags: css, printing

I'm working on a printable list of events, the printer prints one page fine, but cuts off some of the text on the bottom, then it print a second blank page

I've tried everything I know but am at a loss.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In print.css, set `overflow: visible` instead of `overflow: auto` on `div#content`. That fixed it for me in Firefox at least. The definition of overflow auto is: "If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content" -- but scroll bars don't exist on printed pages.

I'm guessing that since the content div should span across multiple pages, the browser thinks "you're flowing outside your container and must be clipped with a scroll bar". The container in that case is the first page the content div appears on.

Comment: It does not seem to work in Chrome, but works fine for me in IE.

Comment: Same here Jack Thor. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Worked for me in chrome. I was lazy and just added `* { overflow: auto !important; }`

Comment: I applied this solution to an issue we were having and I will say that in Chrome I am seeing little scrollbars all over the place. So, scroll bars do in fact exist on printed pages, apparently - which makes no sense.

Comment: This worked when adding `!important`. So the lazy solution would be `* { overflow: visible !important; }`

Comment: It worked me when I added style specific to print media

@media print{

  body{
    overflow:visible;
  }

}

Comment: * { overflow: visible !important; } worked for me too... thanks

Answer (score 28):

I know this is an old question but here's another, newer way this can happen.

Check if you're using `display: flex;` on the clipped element. It was the problem for me, setting it to `block` fixed it.

Comment: What If I really want it to be flex?

Comment: *{time passes}*  I have one that I apparently need to be flex to get all the items on one line.  I'd like it to print right, too.

Answer (score 13):

I found that setting `display: inline` on container divs also helped.  Some of these great answers here have worked for me in certain situations while in others no.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-cutting-off-here">
        Some long text that gets cut off at the end of the page...
    </div>
</div>
```

Most people set containers to display `block` or `inline-block`.  For me it was cutting off text, and setting it to `inline` circumvented that.  This also makes `width` and `height` irrelevant for the offending container div; which I have found to be a nuisance when printing.

```
@media print {
    .container {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

[Here is a great article that helped me with this solution.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/851-fixing-divs-that-cause-content-truncation-when-printing.htm)

Comment: Display inline worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

If any of the containers you're trying to print are floated, they'll get cut-off like you're seeing.

In your print.css, make sure you turn off all the floating that you can without destroying your layout.  It's a pain, but browser support for printing is weak at best.

Comment: Definitely solved my issue. I put a class that `clear: both;` where it can only be found in print.css

Answer (score 3):

Are you already using the `print` value for the `media` attribute for your stylesheet like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

You might also want to use `page-break-before` attributes for elements that you don't want to break.

Comment: yes, the print stylesheet is definitely being used

the page is really just a long list of tables, I don't really want a page break before each one

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved this problem in ie7. This was in a Sharepoint project, which had various table cells and/or divs set to height:100%. When printed, it would print long forms, the first page or 2 would print as usual, then blank pages instead of the rest.

In my print stylesheet, I set those tables & divs to height: auto, and now it prints fine.

I'm having a different problem in IE8 now. UGH!

Answer (score 1):

if `overflow:visible;` not works, try `overflow-y:visible;`

(i had `body{overflow-y:scroll;}`, and `body{overflow:visible;}` in print.css not rewrited it...)

Comment: Im using @print {}, `body{overflow:visible;}` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding `overflow:visible;` and give it `padding-right: 30px;` to substitute for the scroll bars width.

Comment: This is not so helpful. Its not clear to what element you added these styles.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and have been scouring the internet for a solution that fit my specific needs. In my case I had about 7 tables nested in a larger table. The only way I was able to get the entire web page to print and display in print preview correctly was to use page breaks. Page breaks are CSS properties that allow you to specify and/or force page breaks by attaching the property to block elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before

Answer (score 0):

just setting **display: inline** solved my same problem.

Reference link I got, https://www.bennadel.com/blog/851-fixing-divs-that-cause-content-truncation-when-printing.htm

Answer (score 0):

I setup my print sheet to only print the modal content. My fix was to make the modal `position: absolute;`. My modal was originally `position: fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `overflow:visible;` for `body` solved the problem.

```
body {
        overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue to. In my case, this was due to an

```
position: fixed;
```

Element. I changed this to

```
@media print{
   position: relative;
}
```

Now I even see new elements that were behind my fixed element, and no cutting off at the bottom anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If the items on the page are getting partially cut off, adding an :after element of 10px did it for me.

```
<div class="print-row">
  <div class="print-items">
    <div class="print-item"></div>
    <div class="print-item"></div>
    <div class="print-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.print-items {
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.print-item {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.print-item:after {
  position: relative;
  display: block;   
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

for me, the issue was this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

which putting any value other than 1 for initial scale solves my problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8"/>
```